# Getting Build Error " ERROR in NgSemanticModule is not an NgModule " Even after adding dependencies and importing to mail module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, semantic-ui

I have shared my module , component and package file here , my trying to use click event with `ngif` but still getting the error. 
The error it showing is "ERROR in NgSemanticModule is not an NgModule"
am not able to understand if this error is because of semantic-UI dependency or its happening because am missing something in click event

Can any one help thanks in advance.

```
    // app.module.ts
    import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
    import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
    import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component'; //import home components
    import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component'; //import about component
    import { NgSemanticModule } from 'ng-semantic';
    import { routing }  from './app.routing';

    @NgModule({
    imports:      [ BrowserModule, routing , NgSemanticModule,CommonModule ], //other modules the app depends on
    declarations: [ AppComponent, AboutComponent, HomeComponent ], // declare all derectives and components
    bootstrap : [ AppComponent ] // root component to bootstarp
    }) 
    export class AppModule { }


//app.component.ts
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class AppComponent { 
  isActive:boolean = true;
  isCollapsedMenu() {
    this.isActive = !this.isActive;
  }

}


//package.json

{
  "name": "angularapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng-semantic": "^1.1.13",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "1.1.16-11",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^1.7.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.77",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
import { NgSemanticModule } from 'ng-semantic/ng-semantic';
```

if you are using angular-cli, try this,

add the following to the file **`ng-semantic.d.ts`** in the ng-semantic node package:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

...

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        NgSemanticModule
    ]
})
export declare class NgSemanticModule {
}
```

**[`Reference`](https://github.com/vladotesanovic/ngSemantic/issues/149)**

Comment: are you using angular-cli?

Comment: yes am using angular-cli , even in console am getting one error " Can't bind to 'ng-if' since it isn't a known property of 'span'" this can be the reason ?

Comment: still the issue :(